# Connecting two computers possible RDC

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, remote-desktop

OK. I have two computers one is a windows vista the other is a windows 7/8. how do I set up a connection between the two so the windows 7/8 can take control of the mouse and key board so the win 7/8 pc's keyboard and mouse will control the vista pc. They are both using a different wireless network. Any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn on Remote Desktop, press `start` and go to the `Control Panel`. Click on `System` and on the left will be link labelled `Remote settings`. Click that and a new windows will appear with the title `System Properties`. On the 'Remote' tab, there's a header 'Remote Desktop' with three radio buttons. If you are set-up on a domain, you can select 'Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication', else click to 'Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop'. Follow this procedure for both computers.

On one computer, open up a command-prompt and type `ipconfig` to find your IP (should be something like 192.168.x.y).

On the other, press `Win+R` and type `mstsc`. Enter the IP address of the other computer and log in.

Comment: I am having problems with this as the windows vista pc as it is a home basic.

Comment: I don't think Vista Home has native remote support so you might need to use third-party software. [This article](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/02/12/add-remote-desktop-access-to-windows-vista-home-editions/) mentions TightVNC but I'll keep looking for other ways